# I can't undo a partition on my macbook

Tags: macos, disk-utility, partition

I want to "delete" disk0s4, but it isn't appearing in the Disk Utility app.  This is from a failed attempt to install Ubuntu, how can I delete this partition?

Here is the diskutil list output:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *250.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            189.2 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
   4:                        EFI                         60.0 GB    disk0s4
```

Comment: Buscar웃  this is a failed attempt to install ubuntu, how can i delete this partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone saying not to delete it because it's the EFI partition, it's not. "EFI EFI"(disk0s1) is the real EFI partition. The new EFI partition is just one that was improperly created during OP's failed installation of Ubuntu.

This will erase the partition and make it show up in Disk Utility(change `PartitionName` to whatever you want):

```
sudo diskutil eraseVolume JHFS+ PartitionName disk0s4
```

Now you can remove the partition like normal in Disk Utility([source](https://www.idownloadblog.com/2015/06/20/how-to-delete-partition-mac/)):

> 1. Open Disk Utility.
> 2. Click the partition that you wish to delete under the logical
>      volume.
> 3. Click the Erase tab and make sure Mac OS X Extended (Journaled) is selected.
> 4. Click the Erase button.
> 5. Click the logical volume.
> 6. Click the Partition tab.
> 7. Highlight the partition that you erased in step 4.
> 8. Click the ‘-‘ sign and click Remove.
> 9. Use the drag handle to reallocate the space back relinquished
>      by the deleted partition.
> 10. Click Apply → Partition.

Comment: Thank you, I was already out of space. 
If I wrote something wrong, it's because I used google translator

Comment: Well, it worked, but I can not resize disk0s2

Comment: @LucasOliveiraFerreira Doesn't Disk Utility have an option for removing partitions?(see [here](https://www.idownloadblog.com/2015/06/20/how-to-delete-partition-mac/))

Comment: Well, there is a partition called free space, when I try to erase the space it automatically goes to Recovery HD, and when I press command and try to drag to adjust the Macintosh HD the maximum that goes is 189gb